# Could not pull Docker image: fpco/stack-build:lts-17.12 — bad file descriptor

Tags: docker, haskell, haskell-stack

Following the steps [mentioned in the Stack documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/docker_integration/), this is `stack.yml`:

```yaml
docker:
  enable: true
local-bin-path: ./build/
resolver: lts-17.12
packages: [.]
extra-deps: []
```

Running `stack build` results in the following error:

```
Pulling image from registry: 'fpco/stack-build:lts-17.12'
fork/exec /usr/local/bin/com.docker.cli: bad file descriptor
Could not pull Docker image:
    fpco/stack-build:lts-17.12
There may not be an image on the registry for your resolver's LTS version in
your configuration file.
```

Despite the lts-17.12 tag [definitely existing on Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/layers/fpco/stack-build/lts-17.12/images/sha256-1c70bdef874125a003f0ce0e4a48e65103e4a8fee49f74c485d8ea05088a2bf5?context=explore). Adding the specific image hash in `stack.yml` doesn't help.

Is there anything special to do or to add to `stack.yml` to overcome this error?

Comment: It's just a guess, but from the output it seems that when Stack calls docker in order to pull the image it fails to actually run docker itself - hence the `fork/exec ...` line. Stack then sees that the whole step failed and guesses that the image is missing. I think there's a problem with your docker installation itself.

Comment: I would try to see why Stack expects to be able to execute `/usr/local/bin/com.docker.cli` which seems to be missing on your computer.

Comment: Do you have a M1 Mac?

Comment: A friend was having similar problems, and she is using m1 MAC as well. question, are you running this inside a script as well?

Answer (score 0):

Just run `docker pull fpco/stack-build:lts-17.12` in your terminal, and try your command(maybe `stack setup`) again.